# Silverlight / Windows Phone Licensing

Tags: silverlight, windows-mobile, licensing

I don't get it. Can anyone tell me, if I can use Silverlight for my commercial projects? What I mean in specific is to use Silverlight technology for service where users can play games for subscription. As far I know, flash allows that. What's with Silverlight?

And second question is - does it look the same with Windows Phone, when I want to deliver those games for mobile?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Silverlight freely for commercial projects

No, your desktop Silverlight app won't work without modification on Windows Phone